# Setting UIWebView width to show all content

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I need to adjust the width of UIWebView so that the whole text is displayed within the view and the user need not scroll to read the text.

i've tried various methods to achieve this but without much success, i tried to set the width after webViewDidFinishLoad method gets called, but the content too much and is not readable, i see iphone app such as Reeder show the entire content without the need to scroll horizontally,

if there's a way to but each line of the shown text then go another line and but the rest, instead of butting the entire line in single line and becomes unreadable, hope you understand my point

note that scalesPageToFit is set to YES

any ideas folks ?!

Answer (score 2):

You can define that **inside HTML** text file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Title</h1>
<p>Stuff and... well, more stuff</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is may be use to create the content size with your view for that following may be helpful to You.

```
 NSString *tmp =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>body{background-color:transparent;}</style></head><body><p style=\"text-align:justify; font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;line-height:18px;\">%@</p></body></html>",[dict valueForKey:@"description"]];

self.web.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.web loadHTMLString:tmp baseURL:nil];
```

Happy codeing

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Answer (score -1):

In HTML, you can set the width and height of the body according to the size of the webview. did you try this option? This will be good instead of changing the webview's size.

Answer (score -2):

just set the code like `webView.sizeToFit = YES;`